Has Nightcrawler, in any canon, teleported into a solid object?
I was reading some of the recent questions about Nightcrawler, and it led me to my own question.
It's common knowledge that Nightcrawler doesn't like to do blind teleports for fear of colliding with a solid object (and has on occasion put himself in a dangerous position to avoid doing so), but is there every proof that this is actually a risk? Perhaps a situation in a What If or alternate universe where he teleported into a solid object and was injured/killed? A situation where he was shown to do it and sustained a recoverable injury like having to be cut free from teleporting into a cable, or that it merely caused him great pain as he was forced to reform alongside the object he would have intersected?

This was something I wondered too as a kid with my relatives, when we had watched the 2nd X-Men movie. I think it's because the movie character mentioned the risk of getting stuck in wall when teleporting to an unknown area through a door or something.

According to this reddit poster yes, he's teleported into solid objects a few times - with the implication being it would kill him. Here's an example in Excalibur #72:

"Overshooting" his target leads him to merging with the rock, with the caption text explaining that this can kill. (Luckily Kitty is with him, and uses her phasing abilities to save him).
And another example from X Men Gold #17:

Again, the implication is it would kill him, but this time he survives because heaven refuses to let him in.


Thank you. That does answer my question.

God hates demon mutants?!
